# How to add new field in checkout that is displayed in order view in backend

Tags: magento

I am totally new to Magento. Still learning, so I am confused about where to start off when I have to do something new.

I have to add just another input field in the checkout that gets saved in the order and displayed in the back-end.

So can someone give me directions? It can probably be implemented in an existing extension, but I don’t really have a clue. Any help and explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @KeyurShah - Sorry, it didn't help me (I mean the tutorials that you gave me), my problem is different, that is why I didn't accept it.

Comment: You can try out this extension for adding custom fields - http://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-additional-checkout-attributes-fields.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem a popular solution is to utilize the order "agreements" for comments.

[My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168777/magento-custom-fields-on-checkout/10183249#10183249) has lots of tips

And [this blog](http://lastdropofink.co.uk/tools/magento/how-to-enable-order-comments-for-magento/) specifically talks about installing a free extension and his explanation of the process is  simple and thorough.